# Regarding Image processing/ or Jpeg format without library

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I am trying to write a python code to download and get the detail of image resolution and size and rescale it to (320*568) convert it into base64 string and save it in JSON format.

input : any jpeg image

output : JSON

> { "image64":"encoded string",
>    "size":"size of image",
>   "resolution":"resolution of image" }

till now i have done this by this way:

```
from PIL import Image 

a=Image.open("DSC_2561.jpg")

print(a.size)

a=a.resize((320,568))
```

how to proceed from here?

Comment: What's the difference between image resolution and image size?

Comment: @Eypros: people that use “resolution” to mean number of pixels do it wrong. Resolution means the size of the smallest distinguishable detail. In digital photography it is typically used for dots per inch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
from PIL import Image 
import os


def encodeBase64(path):
    img= Image.open(path)
    img= img.resize((320,568))
    data = img.encode("base64")
    json = { "image64": data, "size":os.stat(path).st_size, "resolution":img.size[0] + "x" + img.size[1] }
    return json
```